# How can I use += with jQuery selectors easier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've taken the following example from JS Bin:

#### HTML

```
<p id='js'>Hello, World!</p>`
```

#### JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('js').innerHTML += ' – this was inserted using JavaScript';`
```

Now, I'd like to do the same with jQuery. Since I couldn't find a way to use **+=** with jQuery selectors (otherwise I wouldn't ask this question), here is the long way:

```
var js = $('#js').html() + ' – this was inserted using JavaScript';
$('#js').html(js);
```

I use jQuery because it's syntax is shorter and simpler. But these two codes have almost the same length.

This does not work:

```
$('#js').innerHTML += ' – this was inserted using JavaScript';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery, you can use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead.

Your `$('#js').innerHTML += ' – this was inserted using JavaScript';` would work with a `[0]`, though, e.g.:

```
$('#js')[0].innerHTML += ' – this was inserted using JavaScript';
//      ^^^--- here
```

...because you can access the raw DOM element that way. But it's a bad idea to append content via `innerHTML` because it makes the browser work really hard: First it has to loop through its internal DOM equivalent, serializing it into an HTML string, then it has to re-interpret the new HTML after you've done your `+=`. (Granted the latter will be *really, really fast* because rendering HTML into their internal structures is *what browsers do* and they're highly optimized for it, but the former may not be fast at all.)

Comment: Woah! These were really quick answers! Thanks very much! @AndreKR got a vote up too, but this answer is more detailed.

Comment: +1 @T.J.: So if you're using the DOM API directly, I assume a person should create a text node and do a `appendChild` instead?

Comment: @patrick dw: It totally depends on what you're doing and how much of it you're doing. If you're adding a *lot* of content, it seems a bit counter-intuitive but you're better off using `innerHTML` (which jQuery will do behind the scenes, indirectly), because (again) browsers are highly optimized to read HTML text and convert it into their internal structures. When you add a *lot* of content via JavaScript, you're having to go back and forth between the JavaScript engine and the DOM engine, and you're doing it via an API that may not match for the internals, etc., and it can end up being slow.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#js').append(' – this was inserted using JavaScript');
```